# GetText переводимые слова в html шаблонах

Tags: php, html, gettext

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся с проблемой, определения языка при создании .po файла командой xgettext

По умолчанию данная команда сама определяет язык по расширению файла (например .php), в моем же случае пользуюсь (.html) шаблонами, которые впоследствии парсятся на php.

GetText такого языка не знает и выкидывает ошибку

```
xgettext --from-code=utf-8 index.html
xgettext: warning: file 'index.html' extension 'html' is unknown; will try C
```

Пользоваться параметром --extract-all нет никакого желания, т.к. образуется куча ненужного мусора.

Указание --language=html в библиотеке не предусмотрено:

```
xgettext --language=html index.php
    xgettext: language '=html' unknown
```

При использовании php файлов : < ?php _("ololo") ?> - .po файлы корректно создаются

**Собственно главный вопрос - как подружить GetText c html файлами?**